# Send form to controller in ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

This is my form

```
<form id="postProblemForm" action="/Problems/Post"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" id="problemSubject" name="problemSubject" class="inp-form"/>
            <input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile"/>
            <textarea rows="" cols="" class="form-textarea" id="problemDescription" name="problemDescription"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Post" id="btnPostProblem"  style="width:70px;"/>

    </form>
```

following is JS

```
$("#postProblemForm").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this);
                var url = $this.attr('action');
                var dataToSend = $this.serialize();
                var callBack = function (isPosted) {
                                    if (isPosted) { alert("posted successfully"); } }
                $.get(url,dataToSend,callBack);

            });
```

Following is Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
        public bool Post(FormCollection form) 
        {
            string subject = form["problemSubject"];
            string description = form["problemDescription"];
            var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();

            return true;

        }
```

But controller method is not being called. Plese help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload files using AJAX. I see that your form contains a file input but this won't work with AJAX. Also you are using a `$.get` whereas you probably wanted to `$.post` the contents. Another issue with your action is that it should return an ActionResult and not boolean types. For example you could return a JsonResult for tat matter.

If you want to be able to upload files with your form you could use a client side upload plugin such as [`Uploadify`](http://www.uploadify.com/), [`Fine Uploader`](http://fineuploader.com/) or the [`jQuery.form plugin`](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Here's for example how your code might look like with the jQuery.form plugin:

```
$('#postProblemForm').ajaxForm(function(isPosted) {
    if (isPosted) { 
        alert('posted successfully');
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok its fine. But i want client side validation, then have to send form to controller. What should be done?

Comment: Client side validation has absolutely nothing to do with AJAX. Those are 2 different notions. You could perfectly fine have client side validation enabled and still leave the form submit as a regular form. For example let's suppose that you wanted the `problemSubject` field to be required. Just decorate your view model's property with the `[Required]` attribute and then use a helper to generate the field instead of hardcoding it as you did: `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ProblemSubject)`. Then include a corresponding validation placeholder: `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ProblemSubject)`.

Comment: ... and finally include the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a `GET` on a controller method that accepts a `POST` request. You need to change it to:

```
$.post(url,dataToSend,callBack);
```